# When Im trying to push an _id into an array of ObjectId Typescript throws an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

This is the code :

```js
async function create(data: any) {
    try {
        //Creates and order
        let createdOrder = await model.create(data);

        //Push into bike orders array the id of the newly created order
        let bike = await bikeModel.findById(createdOrder._id);

        bike?.orders.push(createdOrder._id);
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(`[${RESOURCE}:create] controller error:${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Argument of type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: typeof mongoose.Types.ObjectId; ref: "Order"; }'.
  Type 'ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: typeof ObjectId; ref: "Order"; }': type, refts(2345)
```

And this is my model :

```js
const bikeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
model: String,
color: String,
location: String,
rating: String,
available: String,
orders: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Order',
    },
],
```

});

I tried almost everything but it doesnt seem to let me do anything

Comment: So you create an order with `model`, and use `bikeModel` to find a bike with the (unique) `_id` of the order you just created? Seems strange.

Comment: What you're pusing into the `orders`  array is not an order, as you have it defined. You're pusing an `ObjectId`... You need to wrap that in an object with the missing properties...

Comment: @robertklep Eh, no, he's adding the order `id` to a list of orders on that bike model...

Comment: @Cerbrus that's actually perfectly valid (at least for Mongoose, TS may be overly strict in this case)